# Using Feature Flags while registering the dependency

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, feature-flags, microsoft-extensions-di

I'm new to using Feature Flags.

In a development team with 5-7 developers, where each possibly working on different Feature, merging to master/main every PR (Trunk) on nearly daily routine, how can I prevent master branch code eventually looks like Spaghetti with methods having

```
do something
if flag1 enabled then..
   do something
if flag2 enabled then..
   do something
if flag3 enabled then..
   do something
..
..
```

I thought of using the flags while registering to the IoC like:

```
if flag1 register Implementation_X1 to Interface_X else register Implementation_X2
if flag2 register Implementation_Y1 to Interface_Y else register Implementation_Y2
..
..
```

This will allow me to handle all conditions of Feature Flags in single place (or at least where resolving the dependencies), will prevent code being "dirty" with multiple conditions that are not related to actual business logic flow, unit tests won't know on the Feature Flags as they will be covering each implementation separately.

Thing is, I can't find any article explaining this way for using Feature Flags so I thought I might be missing something.

Comment: Which technology, platform and DI Container are you working with?

Comment: ASP.NET Core (C#) with it's native IoC

Comment: I think that how and where to switch depends a lot on a specific feature. There are many options to choose from. There is a [Feature Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core?tabs=core6x) built-in in the framework now, but it rather depends on letting classes themselves decide what code to execute (by injecting the `IFeatureManager` into a class and calling its `IsEnabledAsync` method. In your case, however, you seem to be able to swap complete implementations, which allows you to do if else checks in the startup path.